# Group week names based on start and end time

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array(
       [mon] => Array
    (
        [start] => 09
        [end] => 18
        [hours] => 9
    )

[tue] => Array
    (
        [start] => 09
        [end] => 18
        [hours] => 9
    )

[wed] => Array
    (
        [start] => 09
        [end] => 18
        [hours] => 9
    )

[thu] => Array
    (
        [start] => 09
        [end] => 18
        [hours] => 9
    )

[fri] => Array
    (
        [start] => 00
        [end] => 21
        [hours] => 21
    )

[sat] => 
[sun] => 
);
```

Now my task is able to display in simple format like

```
Mon-Thu    Fri
09 - 18    00-21
```

So How can we transform above array into simple array to display required format at client

I tried following code, but it is giving dates group by,

```
  $workHours = $bhr->workingHours;
$days = array_keys($workHours);
$workHoursInfo = array_values($workHours);
$result = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($workHoursInfo);$i++){
    $info1 = $workHoursInfo[$i];
    if(empty($info1))            continue;
    for($j=1;$j<count($workHoursInfo);$j++) {
        $info2 = $workHoursInfo[$j];
        if(empty($info2))            continue;
        if($info1['start'] === $info2['start'] && $info1['end'] === $info2['end']) {
            if(!in_array($days[$i],$result)) {
                $result[] = $days[$i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Then show your attempt(s)/code

Comment: Then post the code that you have tried and tell us with what exactly you are having problems with.

Comment: So it should say Mon-Thu and not Mon-Tue-Wed-Thu ? What if Monday Tuesday and Thursday have same hours but not Wednesday?

Comment: @TeeDeJee Yes it should show Mon-Thu. If Mon ,Tue and Thu have same hours then it should show comma seperated values like Mon,Tue,Thu  Wed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a function that can help you. I've added some comments to help you with what I did.

```
$workhours = array(
    'mon' => array('start' => '09', 'end' => '18', 'hours' => '9'),
    'tue' => array('start' => '09', 'end' => '18', 'hours' => '9'),
    'wed' => array('start' => '09', 'end' => '18', 'hours' => '9'),
    'thu' => array('start' => '09', 'end' => '18', 'hours' => '9'),
    'fri' => array('start' => '00', 'end' => '21', 'hours' => '21'),
    'sat' => array(),
    'sun' => array(),
);


function format_workhours($workhours){
    $days = array_keys($workhours);

    $temp = array();
    // group by start and end hours
    foreach($workhours as $day => $hours){
        if(isset($hours['start'])){
            $temp[$hours['start'] . '-' . $hours['end']][] = $day;
        }
    }

    // echo with , or - 
    foreach($temp as $i => $work){
        $first = reset($work);
        // Only 1 day so just print it
        if (count($work) === 1){
            echo $first . ': ' . $i . '<br>';
            continue;
        }
        $pos = array_search($first,$days);
        $array = array_slice($days,$pos,count($temp[$i]));
        // all days follow on each other so use a dash
        if($temp[$i] === $array){
            $last = end($work);
            echo $first . '-' . $last . ':' . $i . '<br>';
        }else{ // print all days with a comma
            $workdays = implode(',',$work);
            echo $workdays . ':' . $i . '<br>';
        }
    }
}

format_workhours($workhours);
```

OUTPUT:

mon-thu:09-18 
fri: 00-21